# Как разрешить любому пользователю комментировать запись на моей стене?

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-api

Отправляю пост на свою стенку в фейсбуке "от лица" приложения через graph api (использую facebook php sdk).
Использую параметр privacy со значением `EVERYONE`.
Пост оставляется нормально, но комментировать его могут только мои друзья.

В то же время если отправить пост на страницу из плагина комментариев (с внешнего сайта), то пост могут комментировать все.

Вопрос 1: как разрешить комментирование в первом случае для всех, а не только друзей?
или Вопрос 2: как отправлять комменты второго типа без использования штатного плагина от фейсбук?

Спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

Первый вопрос решить не смог, зато разобрался со вторым:
[Статья](http://www.nadvoe.org.ua/coding/post_46.html)

Для тех кто не пойдет по ссылке:

Получение постов по определенному URL (GET):

```
https://graph.facebook.com/comments/?ids=http://www.nadvoe.org.ua/coding/post_46.html
```

Отправка постов по определенному URL (POST):

```
https://graph.facebook.com/comments/?ids=http://www.nadvoe.org.ua/coding/post_46.html
```

По полученным из ответа id можно получить комментарии по такому адресу:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/DIGITS/comments
```

где DIGITS:

```
   $DIGITS_MOREDIGITS = $json_result['id'];
   $DIGITS = explode('_',$DIGITS_MOREDIGITS);
   $DIGITS = $DIGITS[0];
```

PS перед использованием этого метода URL должен быть единоразово инициализирован:

```
   // следующий запрос обязателен, он инициализирует комментарии для указанного урла
        $context = stream_context_create(array(
            'http' => array(
                'method' => 'GET',
                'header' =>
                    'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux i686; rv:6.0.2) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/6.0.2 FirePHP/0.6'.
                    'Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8'.
                    'Accept-Language: ru-ru,ru;q=0.8,en-us;q=0.5,en;q=0.3'.
                    'Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate'.
                    'Accept-Charset: windows-1251,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7'.
                    'Connection: keep-alive'.
                    'Referer: http://www.nadvoe.org.ua/stud.my/'.
                    'Cookie: '.implode(';',$_COOKIE),
            ),
        ));
        $w = file_get_contents('https://www.facebook.com/plugins/comments.php?href='.urlencode($url),false,$context);
```